# custom management command throws no module found error in virtual env

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am using a virtual environment in django to install all the pip packages. It runs fine when i write command:

```
source env/bin/activate    
python manage.py runserver
```

but when i run custom management command:

```
source env/bin/activate
python manage.py broadcast
```

It throws no module found pika.

I deactivated the virtual env and again activated it but still no luck.

I tried **pip install pika**  but it says requirement already satisfied.

Is there a way to use virtual env in command line?

What can cause this issue?

Comment: do you have the app belonging to the package `pika` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: it looks like your custom command can not resolve the reference. Check your includes in the code for the command.

Comment: I have found an answer.. thanks @tstoev

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer, I have appended the path in settings.py

```
sys.path.append('./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```

and it worked for me.